# How to apply vat for calculated tax amount

Tags: odoo-10

I have problem to add taxes in my project..

I want to add first excise duty as 6% to my product.

And then Apply vat as 5% on total amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create on Tax called Duty6 defined as:

`Tax Computation: Percentage of Price
 Amount: 6
 Advanced: Affect base on subsequent taxes ticked`

Then I create another one called vat5 defined as

`Tax Computation: Percentage of Price
 Amount: 5`

On the product when you sell you need to add duty5 and then vat6.

Hope it helps